# Blog pages reverting changes

Tags: blog

I customized default.aspx, post.aspx, and category.aspx via SharePoint Designer by adding some XSLT List View webparts in the left navigation area (above 'Categories' and 'Archive').  Randomly, though, I'll refresh the blog site, and my changes are gone.

Since these are customized, I cannot understand how/why these changes revert back.  After I see them reverted, I go into SP Designer and I'll see all the original code highlighted in yellow.  My changes are not, though.  Then when I click the 'Advanced Mode' button, the html refreshes and my changes disappear.

Please help me understand the problem and how to correct this.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the blog site"?

Comment: It can be simply pressing F5 after a period of time or leaving and coming back to the blog site.

Comment: It sounds like someone is reghosting the pages or some code or feature activation is wiping them?